# How to create a universal windows shortcut?

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have created a shortcut for my program (under Windows 7), whose target is in a sub-directory. But when I zip everything and send it to my colleague, the shortcut wont work because it the target directory cannot be found, it is like:

Target: `C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\my_program\sub_directory\my_program.ex`e

and the shortcut is in `C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\my_program\`

When I send it to another PC, `my_user_name` directory cannot be found and shortcut doesnt work. How to solve this?

Comment: I don't have a windows 7 machine handy to test, can you edit the shortcut and replace `C:\Users\my_user_name` with `%USERPROFILE%`?

Comment: it says: the name "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\my_program\sub_directory\my_program.exe" is not valid. Make sure path name and file are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file that launches the program. You can then use a relative path.

e.g.

C:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\my_program\launch.cmd

```
cd sub_directory
start my_program.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

possible solutions:

1. place the program with the exe on disk like c:\program\programname\ Location must be the same on all computers.
2. place the program with the exe on the network where you can both access, shortcut is the same
3. edit the shortcut in notepad and change the user